# Not able to map static resources i.e. JS, CSS, images in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, staticresource

I'm not sure how these static resources were loading earlier but after I added one new controller mapping I see no mapping found for static resources warning message in logs.

**No mapping for GET /testproject/org/css/style.css**

Let me explain my project configuration first so that it will be easy to understand the problem.

**All JSP location (view have different folders to separate JSP for different modules)**

```
src/main/java/webapp/views/org/*.jsp  
src/main/java/webapp/views/*.jsp
```

**Static resource location**

```
src/main/java/resources/static/css/*.css  
src/main/java/resources/static/js/*.js  
src/main/java/resources/static/images/*.jpg  
src/main/java/resources/static/fonts/*.ttf
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.contextPath=/testproject
```

After adding last config in **application.properties** now my application URL for any view page will be like

**http://localhost:8080/testproject/dashboard**

Controller mapping for the above URL is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboard(ModelMap map) {return "org/dashboard";}
```

With the above configuration, the static resource path is getting formed as below

**http://localhost:8080/testproject/css/style.css**

With the above config, I was able to load CSS files using the below code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<link href="<core:url value="css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Now as I have dashboard page defined under separate folder **org** so I thought to change my controller mapping to match exactly as folder structure & also it will help me to assign different roles/Access_ROLE for diff modules in spring security.

Spring security config for defining USER_ROLE who can access **org** module pages

*.antMatchers("/org/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ORG')").anyRequest()*

After changing my controller mapping (from **/dashboard** to **/org/dashboard**)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/org/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboard(ModelMap map) {return "org/dashboard";}
```

Now spring security works fine. It is not allowing direct access of dashboard without login or if logged-in user is having different ROLE.

But now my static resource URL is changes now

**http://localhost:8080/testproject/org/css/style.css**

Earlier this URL was

**http://localhost:8080/testproject/css/style.css** (working)

Things I tried to fix this

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
}
```

Added this property in **application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Now in JSP, I'm trying to access CSS with below code, none of them worked

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<link href="<core:url value="css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="<core:url value="resources/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="<core:url value="res/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

So I checked in developer tool to see the path created for all above code PFB

```
<link href="<core:url value="css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

http://localhost:8080/testproject/org/css/style.css

```
<link href="<core:url value="resources/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

http://localhost:8080/testproject/org/resources/css/style.css

```
<link href="<core:url value="res/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

http://localhost:8080/testproject/org/res/css/style.css

Let me know what exactly I'm doing wrong here. I know above code will work but some configuration I'm missing or configured wrong.

I've tried to capture all possible details which may cause this issue. Let me know if need more details.

## **Update 2**

I created simple spring MVC project which can be downloaded form below link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-WqLnuEH2BffvcwBil7QcKcxqPay214Y/view?usp=sharing

few doubts

**static resource loads normally with below code, with or without resource handler mapping in MvcWebConfig.java** just uncomment line 4 & comment line 5 in welcome.jsp css will load.

the only change i made is "/" in value parm before **css/test.css**.

```
<link href="<core:url value="/css/test.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

**but after adding resource handler , i see 404 error, help me to resolve this issue**

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/css");
    }
```

JSP CHANGES

```
<link href="<core:url value="/resources/test.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

can any one please explain what is the difference between all these mapping or let me know if any of them are wrong.

assuming **src/main/java/resources/static/css/*.css**  is static folder structure.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/css");

registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");

registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

below will work as i've changed handler mapping (**myresources**) other than folder structure

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/myresources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/css");
```

when i should use classpath in locations ?

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/css");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Folder Structure]

below code worked for me

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

<link href="<core:url value="/res/css/test.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

### or

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

<link href="<core:url value="/resource/css/test.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

none of them worked given below

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/css");
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define a global static resources handler. Look at your `web.xml` adding a filter chained with your security config (or not, as you need to). Or inside your `WebMvcConfig.class` file.

Edit: Added Examples from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

**Method 1)** In your web.xml or app.xml config :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
```

In your views.jsp :

```
<c:url value="/assets/myCss.css" />
```

**Method 2)**

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/assets/**
```

then you just put "/" before and the resolver will handle the job.
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<link href="<core:url value="/assets/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

**Method 3)** Change default static resources locations

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/assets/,classpath:/static-files
```

**Method 4)** WebMvcConfigurer

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry
              .addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/assets/");    
        }
    }
```

**IMPORTANT** : With Spring Security (and with other security libs too) you must provide a safe pass-away to your static resources :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="permitAll" />
```

**Previous answer :**
Maybe your path must be absolute to resolve your static resources. Otherwise your handler config will not resolve them :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<link href="<core:url value="/res/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, is there any other way than giving absolute path? as earlier without absolute path it was working fine. I can change the controller mapping & in security config also i can give  path pattern for each controller mapping to make it work , but with this approach my security config will have mapping for each page in future which is not good approach.

Comment: Update : You must define a global static resources handler. Look at your `web.xml` adding a filter chained with your security config (or not, as you need to). Or inside your `WebMvcConfig.class` file.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, i already tried adding resource handler in WebMvcConfig.class file, if you are referring to do this with different approach, can you please share some code or any link to refer.

Comment: thanks @ThierryB , your example gave little clarity on spring mvc static resource concept, i create simeple spring mvc project to see how this works, still have few doubts. please refer Update 2 section in Question